# Should review history show all edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

So when going through review and seeing something that looks like it should be improved, I have been clicking on the question at hand and trying to better figure out what was being asked, and then use the edit button from there.  However it seems the history within the new review window only tracks edits that were made without ever leaving the review section.

I don't think it would be such a bad thing to show all edits in the history window even if they weren't in the context of the review page.  Even if you weren't planning on reviewing, but you saw a poor post and edited it; I feel like it's all accomplishing the same task and should be logged in the same place.

Comment: The review panel has always worked like this. If you don't do it from within the panel, it doesn't count.

Comment: @animuson I realize this, but a review is a review, I feel like listing them all in the same place would add some value.